# Liferay hide sites depending on roles

Tags: liferay-6

In one requirement I need to hide some sites (from the top right menu ) depending on the role of the user .

Right now if the user X doesn't have the access to site ABC but he can still sees the site in the top right My Site menu. When he clicks on it he goes there and sees message saying you are not authorized. Instead of this I want to hide those site which the user doesn't have access to.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this scenario..Is user X member of the ABC site?If yes,only then should the site be visible & accessible to him in top left drop down or please specify the special scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's  [a link] , i hope this will help you , http://findnerd.com/list/view/Hiding-My-Sites-Menu-in-Docbar-in-Liferay/1940/

Update :

You can hide the "My Sites" menu from Liferay Docbar by creating hook. In my example i am hidding the menu option for all the users except those whose role is Administrator. You need to Hook the html/taglib/ui/my_sites/page.jsp
Add the following code to check whether the logged in user is administrator role.

```
boolean isAdminUser=permissionChecker.isOmniadmin();
```

Hence if the logged in user is Administrator we are showing the My Sites menu else hidding it. I added extra condition of isAdminUser in following code for same.

```
<c:if test="<%= !mySiteGroups.isEmpty() && isAdminUser %>">
```

Following is the code snippet from page.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/html/taglib/init.jsp" %>
<%
String[] classNames = (String[])request.getAttribute("liferay-ui:my_sites:classNames");
String cssClass = GetterUtil.getString((String)request.getAttribute("liferay-ui:my_sites:cssClass"));
boolean includeControlPanel = GetterUtil.getBoolean((String)request.getAttribute("liferay-ui:my_sites:includeControlPanel"));
int max = GetterUtil.getInteger((String)request.getAttribute("liferay-ui:my_sites:max"));
if (max <= 0) {
    max = PropsValues.MY_SITES_MAX_ELEMENTS;
}
List<Group> mySiteGroups = user.getMySiteGroups(classNames, includeControlPanel, max);
boolean isAdminUser=permissionChecker.isOmniadmin();
System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n  isAdminUser \n\n\n\n\n\n"+isAdminUser);
%>
<c:if test="<%= !mySiteGroups.isEmpty() && isAdminUser %>">
    <ul class="taglib-my-sites <%= cssClass %>">
        <%
        PortletURL portletURL = new PortletURLImpl(request, PortletKeys.SITE_REDIRECTOR, plid, PortletRequest.ACTION_PHASE);
        portletURL.setParameter("struts_action", "/my_sites/view");
        portletURL.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
        portletURL.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);
        for (Group mySiteGroup : mySiteGroups) {
            String escapedSiteName = HtmlUtil.escape(mySiteGroup.getName());
            boolean showPublicSite = mySiteGroup.isShowSite(permissionChecker, false);
            boolean showPrivateSite = mySiteGroup.isShowSite(permissionChecker, true);
        %>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is also a possible solution but will cause problems when patching/upgrading the portal to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Check is the user is a member of the site. If he should not have access to the site, don't make him a member. The top right menu is generated according to the site membership.